# line 207 pos 15: '0 <= currentIndex && currentIndex < items.length': is not true in Flutter App

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am facing a problem. I want to make a Flutter app where all pages will show in the body like Android Fragment.

I have created a list,

```
int _currentIndex = 0;

List<Widget> pages = [
    const HomeMain(),
    const AdPage(),
    const ImageCleanPage(),
    const HomeMain(),
  ];
```

I have listed here 4 pages.
I also created a Drawer and bottom navigation bar.
I am trying to access 0 and 1 pages from the bottom nav bar, And 0,2,3 from the drawer, like fragments.

I have tried this code,

```
        drawer: SafeArea(
          child: Drawer(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: ListView(
                children:  [
                  DrawerHeader(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.indigoAccent
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 70,
                          height: 70,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                              border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  width: 2.0),
                              image: const DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage('assets/images/logo_image.png'),
                              )
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 15,),
                        const Text("Image Cleaner",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15,
                          ),),
                        const SizedBox(height: 2,),
                        const Text("support.imageclean@gmail.com",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 12,
                            decorationThickness: 15,
                          ),)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListBody(
                    children: [
                      ListTile(
                        leading: const Icon(Icons.home),
                        title: const Text('Home'),
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _currentIndex = 0;
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            // Do something when the home page is tapped.
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        leading: const Icon(Icons.settings),
                        title: const Text('Settings'),
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _currentIndex = 2;
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            // Do something when the home page is tapped.
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        leading: const Icon(Icons.help),
                        title: const Text('Help'),
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _currentIndex = 3;
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            // Do something when the home page is tapped.
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          onTap: NavClick,
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.ad_units),
              label: 'Free Coin',
            ),
          ],
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body:   SafeArea(
          child:  pages[_currentIndex],
        )
    );
  }
  void NavClick(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
```

I am getting this error when I clicked index 2 from the drawer,

```
Failed assertion: line 207 pos 15: '0 <= currentIndex && currentIndex < items.length': is not true.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BottomNavigationBar` always needs to have a `currentIndex` within the range of the number of `items`. So in your code you have

```
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      onTap: NavClick,
      items: const [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: 'Home',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.ad_units),
          label: 'Free Coin',
        ),
      ],
      currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
    ),
```

You have 2 `items` there. Which means that `currentIndex` MUST be 0 or 1. But your code makes it go outside that when making `currentIndex` 2 through the drawer. Note you also can't have it "deselected" or something. So even when you want index 2 you will need to have 0 or 1 selected in your bottom bar. To get rid of the error you maybe want to change the line

```
  currentIndex: _currentIndex,
```

to

```
  currentIndex: (_currentIndex == 0 || _currentIndex == 1) ? _currentIndex : 0,
```

to make it fall back to 0 when it's out of range

Answer (score 0):

The error you encountered indicates that the current index value `_currentIndex` is exceeding the range of items in the `BottomNavigationBar`. In your case, you have two items in the `BottomNavigationBar`, but you're setting `_currentIndex` to 2 when selecting "Settings" in the Drawer. This causes an assertion failure because the valid index range should be between 0 and 1 (inclusive) for your current configuration.

To resolve this issue, you need to adjust the index values in the `onTap` callbacks of the `ListTile` widgets inside the Drawer. Here are the changes you should make:

For the "Home" option, set `_currentIndex` to 0.

For the "Settings" option, set `_currentIndex` to 1.

For the "Help" option, set `_currentIndex` to 2.

By making these adjustments, you'll ensure that the `_currentIndex` value stays within the valid range for the `BottomNavigationBar`. This will resolve the error you encountered and allow your app to function correctly.

Comment: I don’t understand you solution, there is one ```_currentIndex``` So that how can i set 1 mean setting where is adspage?